# Set-AWSProxy in PowerShell Profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

My team and I want to put the Set-AWSProxy command in our PowerShell profile so that we can call it with a simple alias or function rather than looking up the required parameters with each new session. This command works fine when run straight:

```
Set-AWSProxy -Hostname <blah> -Port 80  -BypassList <blahblah>
```

When I add that command as either an alias or a function and add it to the PS Profile, the command runs without error, but no more AWS commands work. Commands time out with "Unable to connect to the remote server."

```
Function Set-Proxy {
Write-Output "Setting AWSProxy..."
Set-AWSProxy -Hostname (blah) -Port 80  -BypassList (blahblah)
}
```

Edit to add: Creating the function directly at the command line (not from the profile) causes the same result: no error, but no functionality either. Neither does making the function global change anything. It feels like there's something about the Set-AWSProxy cmdlet that will only work as a straight command-line command.

Comment: How have you configured an example alias?

Comment: I tried using an alias first until I saw that Aliases don't play well with parameters. So I've written a function:

Comment: Are you trying to use proxy for certain addresses and not the entire internet? Please note, that running any AWS command, will require it to be able to connect its endpoint.

Comment: Yes, I'm only trying to connect to the two proxies my company has set up for AWS. The command as is works fine when run straight from a command line or PowerShell window. But enclose the command within a function, and it fails.

Comment: Well, all that cmdlet does is, it creates a variable named AWSProxy. You can verify that by running $Variable:AWSProxy ; $Variable:AWSProxy.gettype().fullname -- You may want to create your function, lets say Function Set-Proxy {
Write-Output "Setting AWSProxy..." by 1) creating the proxysettings and then 2) adding the settings the AWSProxy variable and you should be set.. let me know how it goes.

Comment: ok -- I did a test function could not add here -- putting in answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function Set-Proxy {
    Write-Output "Setting proxy..."

    $proxySettings = [Amazon.PowerShell.Common.ProxySettings]::new()
    $proxySettings.Hostname= "10.0.0.1"
    $proxySettings.Port = "8938"
    $proxySettings.BypassList = "169.254.169.254"

    if($variable:AWSProxy) {
        #variable already exist
        # do anything else - or just set it with the desired value
        Remove-Variable -Name AWSProxy
        New-Variable -Name AWSProxy -Value $proxySettings -Visibility Public -Scope Global
    }
    else {
        New-Variable -Name AWSProxy -Value $proxySettings -Visibility Public -Scope Global
    }

}
```

Comment: That did the trick, Ketanbhut. I had to add "Install-Module AWSPowershell" to the first line of the function, but otherwise it's all good. Thank you.